# ToggleButton dissapears when make background transparent

Tags: android, xml, android-2.3-gingerbread

I try to make some XML layout in Android Studio. I need my app to be compatible with API 10 and higher. My layout have some switch buttons but Switch is for API 14 or higher. It is why I decide to use Toggle Button instead.

I have made custom selector drawable with two states. And problem starts now.
When I make XML like this:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/reminderRepeatToggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/toggleButton"
    android:button="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

It works perfectly on android higher than API 10 but on 10 ToggleButton simply disappear.
I also tried something like this:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/reminderRepeatToggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/toggleButton"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg"/>
```

and it works on API 10 but it looses it proportions. Any idea how to overcome this? Or maybe you advice different approach to the problem? (not making Toggle but something different).

Thanks for help!

style:

```
<style name="toggleButton">
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/Widget.Button.Toggle</item>
    <item name="android:textOn">@string/blank</item>
    <item name="android:textOff">@string/blank</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Button.Toggle" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_toggle_bg</item>
        <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can You post Your style xml?

Comment: :) and then show me the style referenced to @style/Widget.Button.Toggle

Comment: I think it must be parent="@android:style/Widget" in Your Widget.Button.Toggle style

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make it :(